# Пытаюсь построить график из файл, но выдает ошибку, что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-13a2606a0d41> in <module>
      4 table = pd.read_csv('result.txt')
      5 x = table.values[:, 0]
----> 6 y = table.values[:, 1]
      7 
      8 

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос содержимое `result.txt`. А так, у вас выход за пределы массива

Comment: и желательно -- код, без стектрейса

Comment: @hedgehogues, IMO, в вопросах об ошибках лучше всегда указывать и код и соответствующий `error traceback` (желательно целиком)

Comment: @MaxU так я ж не против стектрейса. Вопрос, чтобы был код. Наверное, плохо выразился

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка говорит о том что вы пытаетесь выбрать второй столбец (с индексом `1`) из массива, полученного из DataFrame `table`, у которого всего один столбец.

`DataFrame.values` возвращает DataFrame преобразованный к соответствующему `Numpy NDArray`.

`pd.read_csv()` по умолчанию использует запятую в качестве разделителя полей. Скорее всего в файле `result.txt` используется другой разделитель или этот файл содержит всего один столбец.